# Android Studio Testing shows Test results 0/0. How can I begin the tests?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, testing

I am doing the Kotlin beginner course in Android Studio - and at the testing phase, **Test results** are always **0/0**. How can I complete these tests?

Code is made by Google Android developers and it should work flawlessly. ( I used the same). App compiles without errors. The code is here:
https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-words-app

I tried all sorts of solutions:

- [Espresso tests not running on Android 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69801259/espresso-tests-not-running-on-android-12)
- [Android instrumented test no tests found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39241640/android-instrumented-test-no-tests-found)
- Upgraded gradle and everything to the latest versions.
- Tried it on Pixel 2 and Pixel 3 emulators

It may have something to do with either the Android Studio Version- Bumblebee or some settings made in the emulator to block testing. I suspect this, because when creating a previous app, at the testing phase the same thing happened (test results 0/0)

Test results says:

> 05/04 21:06:18: Launching 'navigate_to_words_...()' on Pixel 3 API 29.
> App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
> Running tests

> $ adb shell am instrument -w -m    -e debug false -e class 'com.example.wordsapp.NavigationTests#navigate_to_words_nav_component' com.example.wordsapp.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
> Connected to process 10870 on device 'Pixel_3_API_29 [emulator-5556]'.>

What are your thoughts on this? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just see the original [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-words-app/blob/main/app/build.gradle#L33) - you're using the wrong test runner:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Comment: I'm sure this is a correct answer for many, it didn't solve my issues unfortunately.
I did however discover while using Kaspresso, adding in the shell command in the Kaspresso builder used in the TestCase constructor caused the issue for me.
I'll reward bounty anyway as I'm sure others find this answer useful. Thanks!

Comment: doesn't work for me, still see 0/0

Comment: Please any solution?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/77684685/10599979 This solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case tests worked, but haven't started today. I tried:

- invalidate caches and restart,
- edit configuration,
- change settings (Java version, etc.),
- sync project with Gradle files,
- checkout old commits and try to build from there,
- restore default IDE settings,
- wipe emulators,
- build an application.

Then I launched the application and learnt that it didn't start (crashed during start). In Logcat I saw an error and tried to resolve it. In my case it was [Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700486/didnt-find-class-androidx-core-app-corecomponentfactory), but a solution was https://stackoverflow.com/a/74836005/2914140:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in `gradle.properties`.

After that I found that a problem was a bad dependency injection. I fixed it and reverted back `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried everything listed above but nothing worked.

What helped in my case is taking a look into Logcat, where was `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` reported. Then I realized that I initialize `MockWebServer` in my `TestApplication` but I forget to add following call into my `TestRunner`

```
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build())
```

So it might be helpful to check Logcat as well:)